# mail not sent when include url in php code

Tags: php, mailer

i have a problem in php code i have to send a mail with a web address to confirm client mail... the mail its sent with no problem but i include the web page has no error but mail not sent if i comment the line containing the address mail not sent... i try many ways but no one work... what can i doing wrong??? help please.. tnx in advance
heres my code

```
    $qunik=$_POST['unic'];
$kk='https://www.clubreeco.com/ofi_red/anchk_inv_66deh_usr_ytr554433196302.php?enrt_ps_oto='.$qunik.'/';
$k2=stripslashes($kk);
$our_email = "admin@clubreeco.com";
$to =$qinputemail_orig;
$from = $our_email;
$subject = "Welcome to Club Reeco";    
$message = '<html><head></head><body>';  
$message .= '<img src="https://www.clubreeco.com/img/confirm_head.png" alt="Welcome to Club Reeco" />';
$message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
$message .= '<tr><td colspan="2"> &nbsp; </td></tr>';
$message .= '<tr style="background: #eee;"><td height="23"><strong>Name:</strong> </td><td>' . $qinputname          . "</td></tr>";
$message .= '<tr style="background: #eee;"><td height="23"><strong>date:</strong>  </td><td>' . $todayis        . "</td></tr>";
$message .= '<tr style="background: #eee;"><td height="23"><strong>E-mail:</strong> </td><td>' . $qinputemail_orig  . "</td></tr>";
$message .= '<tr><td colspan="2">' . $qinputmessage.'"</td></tr>';
$message .= '</table>';
$message .= 'Click here to activate your acount:';
$message .='<br>';
$message .='<a href="'.$k2.'"> your invitation </a>';
$message .='<br>';
$message .= '</body></html>';

$headers = "Return-Path: admin@clubreeco.com\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'."\r\n";
$headers .= "From: admin@clubreeco.com\r\n";

  mail($to, $subject, utf8_decode($message), $headers) or die ("Failure1");
```

i have 2 days with this my site has recaptcha v3 ans SSL.. any help

Comment: `i include the url has no error but mail not sent if i comment the line containing the url mail not sent`...so it's not sent whether you include the URL or not, by the sound of it (although your lack of any punctuation, capital letters or formatting makes that sentence rather ambiguous)? In that case I'd suggest the URL isn't relevant to the issue

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Why do you **decode** the message content before sending it?